# Scala Spark Task not serializable error in code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Not sure whats wrong with the code below , but its throwing

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

error. Googled about the error, but couldn't resolve.

Below is the code: (Can be copy pasted and executed on `community.cloud.databricks.com` by creating new Scala notebook)

```
    import com.google.gson._    
     object TweetUtils {
          case class Tweet(
               id : String,
               user : String,
               userName : String,
               text : String,
               place : String,
               country : String,
               lang : String
          ) 

       def parseFromJson(lines:Iterator[String]):Iterator[Tweet] = {
            val gson = new Gson
            lines.map( line => gson.fromJson(line, classOf[Tweet]))     
       }

       def loadData(): RDD[Tweet] = { 
           val pathToFile = "/FileStore/tables/reduced_tweets-57570.json"
           sc.textFile(pathToFile).mapPartitions(parseFromJson(_))
       }

       def tweetsByUser(): RDD[(String, Iterable[Tweet])] = {
           val tweets = loadData
           tweets.groupBy(_.user)    
       }  
   } 

   val res = TweetUtils.tweetsByUser()
   res.collect().take(5).foreach(println)
```

**Below is the detailed error Message:**

```
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2548)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:826)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$TweetUtils$.loadData(command-3696793732897971:22)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$TweetUtils$.tweetsByUser(command-3696793732897971:25)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:30)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:84)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:86)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:88)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:90)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:92)
    at line05db6d250e4b42e2b2c1d6b97ba83df533.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3696793732897971:94)
```

Thanks in advance,

Sri

Comment: Could you try to move `case class Tweet` out of TweetUtils  object. TweetUtils  is not serializable.

Comment: Hi Artem Aliev, thanks for your reply. I tried moving the "case class tweet" outside the "object", But I face the same issue "Task not serializable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `TweetUtils` object as `Serializable` and it should work:

`object TweetUtils extends Serializable`

Comment: Hi Partha, I Tried Making the object serializable. But I get the error "Malformed class name"

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what worked is by implementing together both suggestions from " Artem Aliev" and "Partha" together. i.e. by moving "case class Tweet" outside of "TweetUtils object" and also by extending the Object "object TweetUtils extends Serializable"

Thanks to both of you.